# Returning null from native methods using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have some native code which returns a jbyteArray (so byte[] on the Java side) and I want to return null. However, I run into problems if I simply return 0 in place of the jbyteArray.

Some more information:
The main logic is in Java, the native method is used to encode some data into a byte stream. don;t ask.. it has to be done like this. Recently, the native code had to be changed a bit and now it runs horribly horrible slow. After some experimentation, which included commenting out all code in the native method before the return, it turns out that returning 0 causes the slowdown. When returning an actual jbyteArray, everything is fine.

Method signatures for my code:

On the C++ side:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_xxx_recode (JNIEnv* env, jclass java_this, jbyteArray origBytes, jobject message)
```

On the Java side:

```
private static native byte[] recode(byte[] origBytes, Message message);
```

The native code looks something like this:

```
jbyteArray javaArray;
if (error != ERROR) {
    // convert to jbyteArray
    javaArray = env->NewByteArray((jsize) message.size);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(java_array, 0, message.size, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(message.buffer()));
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        error = ERROR;
    }
}
if (error == ERROR) {
    return 0; // Does NOT work - doesn't crash, just slows everything down horrible.
}
else {
    return javaArray; // Works perfectly.
}
```

Does anyone know of any reasons that this could happen? Is it valid to return NULL from a native method in place of a jbyteArray, or is there another procedure to return null back to Java. Unfortunately, I had no luck on Google.

Thanks!

EDIT: Added additional information.

Comment: Why are you returning 0 instead of the array?  Why can't you simply return an empty array?  Please give some more detail about what this native library is supposed to do.

Comment: Could you post some code, at least the method signature and such?

Comment: Well, I specifically want Java to receive "null", not an empty byte array. I _could_ rewrite the Java code to work with that, but I'd really rather not, if possible. I added the method signatures.

Comment: Returning zero does work and does not by itself cause a slowdown. Further information please.

Comment: "Further information please." six years later?

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but I had it too a minute ago...

You say in your question:

```
return 0; // Does NOT work - doesn't crash, just slows everything down horrible.
```

I just gave a try actually, with a `jintArray` as this is what my code has to  allocate and return, unless an error happens (defined by some criteria not related to this topic) in which case it has to return a null result.

It happens that returning `NULL` (defined as `((void*)0)`) works perfectly and is interpreted as `null` when back to the Java side. I didn't notice any degradation of the performances. And unless I missed anything returning `0` with no `void *` cast would not change anything to this.

So I don't think this was the cause of the slowdown you encountered. `NULL` looks just fine to return `null`.

**EDIT**:

- I do confirm, the return value has nothing to do with performances. I just tested a same code returning a null value on a side, and its counterpart returning an object (a `jintArray`) on the other. Performances are similar for `NULL`, a `jintArray` of size 0, and a random `jintArray` of a few KBs allocated statically.
- I also tried changing the value of a caller class's field, and returing void, with roughly the same performances. A very very little bit slower, probably due to the reflection code needed to catch that field and set it.
- All these tests were made under Android, not under Java standalones - maybe this is why? (see comments):

  - An API 17 x86 emulator running under HAXM
  - An API 19 one, running under the same conditions
  - Two API 19 physical devices - an Asus tablet and a Galaxy 5 - running under Dalvik.

Comment: This was a long time ago and I work elsewhere now. However, I do remember it and at the time, if I returned 0/NULL it was dog slow, but if I returned anything else (an empty array for example) it was not. I don't know what my issue was, but I can guarantee that the JVM I was using in 2009 is not the same as the one you were using in 2015. Was it my JVM? Was it my configuration? Was it my JNI setup? We'll never know, but I do know that returning 0/NULL made it really slow.

I don't remember how I solved it in the end. I assume that I either returned an empty array or a 'null' object instance.

Comment: Dalvik is rather different though, I thought? For one, Dalvik is a register-based VM and Oracle's (at the time of this Q, Sun's) JVM are stack-based.  I don't plan on retesting on another JVM now, but I wouldn't expect the same results under Dalvik personally.

Comment: Hi @Dan! Yes, this makes absolute sense. When I wrote this I was using the Dalvik, and nowadays that's even a different one, called Art. This could explain, that's true. I updated my edit section accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There's some asymmetry in your code that struck my eye: you never decide upon the type of object to return, except when returning 'nothing'.  Apparently the `env` object decides how to allocate a `javaSrray`, so why not ask it to return some kind of empty array?  It may be possible that the 0 that you return needs to be handled in a special way while marshaling between jni and java.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that instead of returning 0 (which appears to WORK, ie I get a null back on the Java side, but for some strange strange reason its really slow.. maybe JNI treats it as an error case and returns null because of this as a side effect? and the additional error handling is slowing it down??) that I should be returning some kind of jnull object, but I had no look actually finding one...

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried returning a NULL reference?

This is untested (don't have a JNI development environment at hand at the moment) but you should be able to create a new global reference to NULL and return it like this:

```
return (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, NULL);
```

EDIT That being said, you check if an exception occurs, but do not clear it. That, as far as I can understand, means that it is still "thrown" in the Java layer, so you should be able to use just that as an error indicator; then it does not matter what the function returns. In fact, calling a JNI function other than ExceptionClear()/ExceptionDescribe() when an exception is thrown is not "safe" according to the documentation. That the functions is "slow" might be caused by the ExceptionDescribe() function writing debugging information.

So, if I understand this correctly, this should be a well-behaved function throwing an exception the first time an error occurs, and returning NULL on each subsequent call (until 'error' is cleared):

```
if (error != ERROR) {
    jbyteArray javaArray = env->NewByteArray((jsize) message.size);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(javaArray, 0, message.size, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(message.buffer()));
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
        error = ERROR;
        return 0;
    }
    return javaArray;
} else {
    return env->NewGlobalRef(NULL);
}
```

Again, this is untested since I dont have a JNI environment available right now.

Comment: Thanks for that. Well, the code is still slow if everything is commented out EXCEPT the return 0, so it can't be the call to ExceptionDescribe(). Still a good point though and your code IS a bit cleaner than mine.

Comment: What VM do you use? If it's an open-sourced one, see if you can find out if there's some extra validation step or whatever if a native function returns null :) 
Perhaps it's better to raise an exception in the native code for the 'else' case as well?

Comment: No, using the Sun VM. Yeah, I'm assuming that theres additional error handling code being run when the return value is zero. Anyway, it would be nice to know what the deal here is, but I can fix it in other ways anyway.

Comment: `NewGlobalRef` returns jobject, not jbytearray, and there seems to be no conversion available, can you verify your solution? [Also, not clear to me, what is the semantics of a global reference to NULL... NULL isn't a java object, it can't be garbage-collected... I hope :) So we shouldn't need to have a reference to it to pass it around.]

Comment: @MaxGalkin jbyteArray is actually a typedef of jarray, itself being a typedef of jobject, which is a typedef of void *.